# How do i make the game wait until a funcion is called?

Tags: function, lua, wait, roblox

I was creating a script and i want to know how do i make the game wait until a funcion is called
If someone awnser me,ill be thankful

Comment: You can't make the "game" wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly do not use loops, use events!

To wait for an [event](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=RBXScriptSignal) to happen you can use the wait method, like so:

```
print("Starting to wait for touch")
workspace.Part.Touched:Wait()
print("Touched!")
```

This will wait for the part to be touched before it continues the script.
But ofcourse, other scripts will still run, the game is not "paused", it is just that script's execution that is suspended until the event is fired.

You can also make custom "wait for call" by using for example a [BoolValue](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/BoolValue) like so:

```
local WaitObject = Instance.new("BoolValue")

function WaitOn()
    WaitObject.Changed:Wait()
end

function StopWait()
    WaitObject.Value = not WaitObject.Value
end
```

You can also place the BoolValue in the game and do the wait and stop wait in separated scripts.
If you do it in same script, remember to use different [threads](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Thread_scheduler)

Comment: Actually i was thinking about like repeat wait() until function f1 or anything else

Comment: @arthurgps2 Do not use loops. If you track down what you really are waiting for, you should find a Event that you can use ":wait()" on. If you can't find such a event, look at the "BoolValue" thing i put in my answer, if it ain't what you are looking for, you need to explain your particular problem more clearly.

Comment: Sorry for taking 6 whole years to respond. Yep, that is correct, haha